# Quasi-concave function, if a maximum is global?

Tags: calculus, analysis

I need to show quasi-concavity for a Nash Equilibrium existence proof.

$f(x)$ is continuous and twice differentiable. I can show that whenever $f'(x_0)=0$, then also $f''(x_0)<0$. Further I can show that if $x_0$ such that $f'(x_0)=0$ does not exist, then $f'(x)<0$ for all $x$.

From this it follows that, if it exists, there is a global, i.e. unique, maximum. Right?

Does, then, also follow that $f(x)$ is quasi-concave? Why? By which theorem?
 Thanks!

Comment: For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: There is something called Katzner's criterion from the 1970s. I believe that this criterion should be applicable in your case.

Comment: Thanks! That helps. Katzner's criterion was extended by Crouzeix (1979) in "On second order conditions for quasiconvexity". Then, as I understand, in my one-variable case the only condition for quasi-concavity is basically that whenever $f′(x_{0})=0$, then also $f′′(x_{0})<0$.